# R-squared within for a regression with multiple fixed effects

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, stata, goodness-of-fit

I would like to get the R-squared within for a fixed effect regression with multiple fixed effects (let's say Country, Year, Trimester).
The least squared dummy variable (LSDV) model (`lm` in R/ `reg` in Stata) would only provide the overall R-squared.
The same is true if one uses `areg` (Stata).
Code/packages suggestions for R or Stata are both welcome.

Comment: Your question might be better suited for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). Please consider posting some data and what you tried to address your issue.

Comment: you probably want `lfe` in R and `reghdfe` in Stata

Comment: You just have to time-demean you LSDV model. In `R` the `plm` package should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this dummy data but this time we know exactly the coefficient we want to estimate.

```
library(plm)
library(xtable)
library(texreg)
library(data.table)
set.seed(100)
```

Let's first generate some data with time and individual fixed effect

```
dt <- data.table(epsilon=rnorm(100),ind=rep(1:5,5),time=rep(1:5,each=5),x=rnorm(100,0,2))

dt[,mu:=6*mean(x)*rnorm(20),ind]

dt[,`:=`(delta=10*mean(x)+rnorm(20)),time]

dt[,y:=5*x+mu+delta+epsilon]


> ## head(dt)
##         epsilon ind time         x         mu    delta           y x..bari. x..bar.t
## 1: -0.247885286   1    1 3.1530482 -34.563268 37.74058 18.69467015 3.686294 3.854510
## 2:  1.234916664   2    1 4.2520514 -30.682143 39.75175 31.56477572 3.508577 3.854510
## 3:  0.117692498   3    1 2.2582500  44.240719 37.24573 92.89539109 3.936578 3.854510
## 4: -0.002265777   4    1 1.9168626 -48.510759 38.83342 -0.09529645 3.455571 3.854510
## 5: -1.424864120   5    1 1.7842555 -11.278647 38.77298 34.99074471 4.282104 3.854510
## 6: -1.441965687   1    2 0.5658582  -2.075256 38.41338 37.72545392 3.686294 3.737549
```

estimate model pooled ols

```
pooled <- lm(y~x,data=dt)
```

estimate model individual effects

```
individual..effect <- lm(y~x+as.factor(ind),data=dt)
```

estimate model time and individual effects

```
individual..time..effect <- lm(y~x+as.factor(ind)+as.factor(time),data=dt)
```

create variable  mean over time and mean over individuals

```
dt[,x..bari.:=mean(x),ind]
dt[,x..bar.t:=mean(x),time]
```

Estimate the within estimator

```
within..estimator  <-  lm(y~I(x-x..bari.-x..bar.t),data=dt)
```

Wrapping everything together

```
screenreg(list(pooled,individual..effect,individual..time..effect
               ,within..estimator))

## ==========================================================================
##                             Model 1     Model 2     Model 3     Model 4   
## --------------------------------------------------------------------------
## (Intercept)                   0.50        1.29        4.22 ***    0.73    
##                              (0.33)      (0.77)      (0.80)      (0.44)   
## x                             5.14 ***    5.18 ***    4.99 ***            
##                              (0.21)      (0.22)      (0.18)               
## as.factor(ind)2                          -1.23       -1.08                
##                                          (1.09)      (0.86)               
## as.factor(ind)3                          -0.97       -0.88                
##                                          (1.08)      (0.85)               
## as.factor(ind)4                          -0.95       -0.82                
##                                          (1.08)      (0.86)               
## as.factor(ind)5                          -0.80       -0.59                
##                                          (1.10)      (0.87)               
## as.factor(time)2                                     -3.88 ***            
##                                                      (0.85)               
## as.factor(time)3                                     -3.99 ***            
##                                                      (0.85)               
## as.factor(time)4                                     -1.39                
##                                                      (0.85)               
## as.factor(time)5                                     -5.94 ***            
##                                                      (0.85)               
## I(x - x..bari. - x..bar.t)                                        4.99 ***
##                                                                  (0.29)   
## --------------------------------------------------------------------------
## R^2                           0.86        0.86        0.92        0.75    
## Adj. R^2                      0.86        0.85        0.91        0.75    
## Num. obs.                   100         100         100         100       
## RMSE                          3.34        3.38        2.68        4.44    
## ==========================================================================
## *** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

I will let you explore with `plm` package if you wish to do so.

Comment: Thanks, this is very instructive. Can you aslo post how to do this with the 'plm' package?

Comment: [This](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v027i02/v27i02.pdf) doc would be way better than any of my explanations.